# Flutter - How to trigger push notification from an app to subscribed topic

Tags: flutter

I finished coding my first flutter app, but i am searching for hours of how to trigger push notification to a subscribed topic from an admin app  via a button (send notification) without accessing the FCM console
so other devices can receive the notification

could any one suggest!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build your own API, firebase has support for different backend technologies including nodeJs. Check the link below for more.

[Add the Firebase Admin SDK to your server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

this youtube video helps also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-v5tS0HhCg

Comment: Thank you Menji, Is their any good tutorial helping in building this API?

Comment: I recommend using nodeJS. Link for nodeJS tutorial:[https://www.toptal.com/nodejs/secure-rest-api-in-nodejs], for using firebase with nodeJS:[https://indepth.dev/building-an-api-with-firebase/]

Comment: thankyou, I searched for related topics and found this youtube video helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L-v5tS0HhCg